# About reading string with scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

When I use scanf() to read a string from the keyboard, and the string is declared as

```
char str[ 10 ];
```

, should I use **%10s** or **%9s** to properly limit the number of characters input? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do want to use scanf for this, then please look at the man page http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf ''`String input conversions store a terminating null byte ('\0') to mark the end of the input; the maximum field width does not include this terminator. `'' Based on this, you should use `%9s` as your maximum field specifier if you want to leave room for a `'\0'` in the last position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I use %10s or %9s to properly limit the number of characters input?

You can use but better to use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html#tag_16_142) to read string.

```
 fgets(str, 10, stdin);
```

A terminating null character is automatically appended after 9 characters copied to `str`.

#### 7.21.7.2 The `fgets` function

> Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,
> FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> Description
>   The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`
>   from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional
>   characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. **A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array**.

Comment: Thanks, so, in your answer, I don't need to use 9 because of the terminating '\0' character?